# VB6 apps to Windows Store or AppX?

Tags: vb6, windows-store-apps, windows-store, surface, appx

I have a legacy app not yet ported to .NET created using VB6. I have a high demand from a community with locked down Surface 3 tablets and the only means to install to the tablet is via Windows Store or AppX.

Does anyone know the options available for VB6 desktop applications in this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no upgrade path for vb6 apps to run in the store that I know of.  I think your only option would be to do a rewrite of the app.